# Problem configuring application specific loggin glassfish v3

Tags: glassfish, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I am using java.util.logging in an EJB application running on glassfish v3. I can see the log messages in server.log but i don't seem to be able to configure the logging level in glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties. If I use:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo");
```

To obtain the logger and log with:

```
logger.info("message");
```

then I expect that if I set

```
com.foo.level=WARNING
```

in logging.properties then the message should not logged. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you use .level=WARNING, only WARNING and above severities will be logged. You will have to set it to `FINEST`, `FINER`, `FINE`, `CONFIG` or `INFO` to have `logger.info(anything)` actually do something.